# How to keep the "no cookie" setting (EU cookie law)

Tags: security, cookies, geolocation

I am currently implementing the European cookie law, and I wonder how to keep the "no cookies" decision without using cookies? 
Showing the cookie popup again and again is not very user friendly.

Storing it on Server with an IP Address would conflict with another law (at least here in Germany).

Are there any best practices?

This is my current solution - I add a "no_cookie=1" Paramter to all URLs. Not perfect, but it works:

```js
function getNoCookieUrl(url){
    var param = 'no_cookie=1';
    var output = '';

    //last char is ?
    while (url.charAt(url.length - 1) === '?') {
        url = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);
    }

    //url has anchor
    anchor = url.indexOf('#');
    anchorText = '';
    if (anchor > 0) {
        anchorText = url.substring(anchor);
        url = url.substring(0, anchor);
    }

    if (url.indexOf('?') > 0)
        output = url + '&' + param;
    else
        output = url + '?' + param;

    if (anchor > 0) {
        output = output + anchorText;
    }

    return output;
}

function changeAllLinksToNoCookie(){
    $('a').each(function() {
       var oldHref = $(this).prop('href');
       var newHref = getNoCookieUrl(oldHref);
       $(this).prop('href',newHref);
    });
}
```

Comment: From a strictly technical point of view, ip address means very little, as many residential and mobile users share the same ip.
Therefore ip != user_identification.
If you don't use "tracking" cookies, but only a "technical" cookie, to remember user decision on other cookies, that is allowed here in Italy.
NB.: This issue is more "legal" than technical, and probably is not considered a good question here on SO.

Comment: Currently, I am only looking for technical solutions - how to keep the "no cookie" information within a session. 
The legal thing is also ugly, but as you say this is not the place to discuss that. The code shall be used in 10 EU countries, and every country has its own interpretations of the law.

Comment: localStorage would be an option to store such a “preference” – and maybe use a “technical” cookie as a fallback, if that’s not available.

Comment: The legal side here is really very ugly, as non compliance carries sanctions in the 20K€ range. I think it is possible to pass a session  id info via POST, or as additional parameter within url in GETs. Looks very insecure to me. Otherwise I could think of client side persistent storage, incidentally I found this http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557

Comment: Seems like localStorage is regarded as Cookie as well. https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/290566/is-localstorage-under-the-cookie-law